# PHP: array transformation: modify "array value" to "array key" and "array value" to count(array keys)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with keys from 0-x. I want those values to transform into keys, and in values i want to have an integer of how many occurencies of those former values are.

Here is a vardump:

```
array(16) {
[0]=>
string(2) "25"
[1]=>
string(2) "25"
[2]=>
string(2) "23"
[3]=>
string(2) "23"
[4]=>
string(2) "24"
[5]=>
string(2) "23"
[6]=>
string(2) "23"
[7]=>
string(2) "23"
[8]=>
string(2) "25"
[9]=>
string(2) "19"
[10]=>
string(2) "27"
[11]=>
string(2) "27"
[12]=>
string(2) "27"
[13]=>
string(2) "25"
[14]=>
string(2) "23"
[15]=>
string(2) "01"
}
```

E.g.: 01 is only once in this array, so i want the new array to look like this:

[1]=> int(1)

23 is 6 times in this array, so it should be like this:

[23]=> int(6)

25 is 4 times in my array,

[25]=> int(4)

and so on.

Could you give some thoughts of how i could do it? I think at least one loop "foreach ($array as $key => $value)" is needed, but i can't figue out how to do it by myself.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No need to use any loops; there's a buit-in function that will do it for you. Use [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: Seems like that is just what i need, thank you :)